# Vue click event for arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in items" :id="n" @click="myMethod($event)">{{n}}</div>
```

The array is like

```
items: [mouse, bull, tiger, rabbit, pig, cat, dog, horse]
```

The method is like

```
myMethod: function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

I want to click each div and that div tells me its content, so I bind the content to the id of each div. The problem is I can't access the index of the items in `myMethod()`. I want to use the index of each item for other purposes. How can I access them? Currently I can only pass data to the method through the id attribute.

Comment: You can pass the iterated properties into your method as arguments, eg `myMethod(n, index)`

Answer (score 6):

> I want to use the index of each item for other purposes. How can I
>   access them?

It's very simple, just passing it, like this:

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in items" :id="n" @click="myMethod(index)">{{n}}</div>
```

This is a working example on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/m363rl73oy

Another demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['mouse', 'bull', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'pig', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse']
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(index) {
      alert(index)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="handleClick(index)" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

In case you want to *pass data to the method*, just passing it, like this

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['mouse', 'bull', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'pig', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse']
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(item) {
      alert(item)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="handleClick(item)" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the index into the method like this.

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in items" :id="n" @click="myMethod($event, index)">{{n}}</div>
```